# How to access a dom element in a Angular directive

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to attach a keyup event to a directive in my Angular project.  Here is the directive:

```
angular.module('clinicalApp').directive('chatContainer', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      encounter: '=',
      count: '='
    }
    templateUrl: 'views/chat.container.html',

    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.count = 500;
    }
  };
});
```

And here is the html from the template:

```
<div class="span4 chat-container">
  <div class="chat-body">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="#" method="POST">
      <div class="text-area-container">
        <textarea id="chatBox" class="chat-box" rows="2"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="button-container btn-group btn-group-chat">
        <input  id="comment" class="btn btn-primary btn-small btn-comment disabled"  value="Comment" ng-click="addMessage()"/>
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to access the `chatbox` in my link function and attach the keyup event to it.  I know I can get it with jQuery, but that cannot be the Angular way.  What is the proper way to grab that element from the dom?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can easily do it with Angular' [`element`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element)'  `find()` method:

```
 var chatbox = elem.find("textarea");  // Finding
 chatbox.bind("keyup",function(){      // Binding
     console.log("KEYUP!")
 })
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/S7XdK/

Comment: Perfect.  How about if I want to find by id or class?

Comment: You will need to use full jquery if you want to do that, and wrap your $(element).

Comment: no, id is `angular.element(document.getElementById('some'));`

Comment: you can do `angular.element(document.querySelector('.yourclass'))`

Comment: Why use bind when angular already has ng-keyup? Are you aware that it can cause flaky behavior when the function not wrapped with scope.$apply, and then it's exactly the ng-keyup implementation?

Comment: @haimlit angular not always had `ng-keyup` , it was added only in version 1.1.2 , while my jsfiddle uses only 1.1.1 ; so now instead of down-voting my answer you can post yours one with an updated information about `ng-keyup` , ok?

Comment: I'm sorry if you were offended, but what do you think is better? The reason for the downvote is for missing the scope.$apply, which makes the behavior really not stable. You can update your answer, and I'll switch the downvote to an upvote, I don't mind about mine.

Comment: @haimlit , the question was *"What is the proper way to grab that element from the dom?"* , nothing about angular's apply/digest etc. May be the questioner only wants to put there the `console.log` for testing purposes , why should we explain him things that he didn't ask??

Comment: First of all, there's no need to mention any apply\digest cycles if we'd just use ngKeyUp. Second, you're right, he didn't ask it, but it should be there. I'm only guessing here, but I don't think OP will only be printing to console, it's more likely he'll be changing variables on the scope. In that case I think it's important to alert about this very common pitfall which I see questions about almost every day.

Comment: @RMorrisey what exactly doesnt work for you? just checked it and i do see "KEYUP" message in console

Comment: My mistake. I should've read the code more carefully before making a comment. I was expecting it to do something when the input button was triggered.

Comment: Using angular.element(document.querySelector('.yourclass')) I get and error because .bind() is undefined...

Answer (score 3):

You can use element.find(yourSelector) as previously mentioned, but it is better to use ngKeyUp, similar to how you would use ngClick:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup