# How can i set the margin of footer based on height of other elements, in Angular and no jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

As i say in the question, what i'm trying to achieve is the equivalent of code like these in Angular only:

**jQuery way**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var windowHeight = $(window).height();
  var headerHeight = $('header').height();
  var footerHeight = $('footer').height();
  var contentHeight = $('.content').height();
  var paginationHeight = $('.pagination').height();

  var footerMarginTop = (windowHeight - headerHeight - footerHeight) - (contentHeight + paginationHeight);

  $('footer').on('content.loaded', function() {
    if(footerMarginTop > 0) {
      $(this).css('margin-top', footerMarginTop + 'px');
    }
  }
});
```

On document ready i have to set the margin top of the footer based on the calculation of the height of other elements, after the content of the page is loaded.
Thinking in jQuery is easy to do but in Angular only i didn't find other way except translating it directly like this, with a directory

**Angular way**

```
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('FooterMargin', ['$window', '$document', function($window, $document){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      var windowHeight = $window.innerHeight;
      var headerHeight = $document[0].getElementById('header').offsetHeight;
      var footerHeight = $document[0].getElementById('footer').offsetHeight;
      var paginationHeight = $document[0].getElementById('pagination').offsetHeight;
      var contentHeight = $document[0].getElementById('content').offsetHeight;

      var footerMarginTop = (windowHeight - headerHeight - footerHeight) - (contentHeight + paginationHeight);

      scope.$on('content.loaded', function(){                          
          if(footerMarginTop > 0) {
            attrs.$set('style', 'margin-top: ' + footerMarginTop + 'px');
          }
        }
      });
    }
  };
}]);
```

I've added IDs to my elements to retrieve them in Angular, but even if it's working it seems to me that it is not a good way to do this, and it is also hard to unit testing it.

I can't use jQuery in this project and i've used Angular for other directive for events that are easier to get with it (like modals and dropdowns) in a satisfactory way

Can you help me understand how to approach this in a better Angular way?

Comment: Why are you doing this in javascript and not with CSS? Also, you can user Jquery lite which is included in angular.

Comment: i can't use only css, because i have to push the footer to the bottom enough for the user to see the final content of the page above the fold, so i have to calculate everything based on the content height (that is always different).
and i'm not using jqLite because it is not possible to select tags with classes or ids

Comment: You can do it with plain Javascript too.

Comment: i know it is possibile to do this in plain JS, but my question is for find a solution in a more Angular way, since it is not clear to me how to do it.
If there is no solution, i'll stick with the one i've proposed in the question, that is working well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429025/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-a-angular-directive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more Angular way could be to use a **service** and another directive, that defines the elements you want to select and sets their heights to the service.

Your original directive will then retrieve the precalculated height from the new service.

In my example I used a factory `heightFactory` as a service. I also had to add an ugly timeout to wait for the DOM elements to be rendered correctly (and have a size). I think this is what you wanted to achieve with `scope.$on('content.loaded')` in your example also.

Note the usage of the directives in the markup as `set-height="header"` for example, for the element, that has the header height.
After each element registred their height to the service, the return value for `heightFactory.getMarginTop()` will be according to your algorithm.

```js
// this directive will ste the window height and retrieve the margin value from the height service
angular.module('myApp', []).directive('footerMargin', ['$window', 'heightFactory',
  function($window, heightFactory) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

        heightFactory.setHeight('window', $window.innerHeight);

        // delay only for testing purposes, remove this
        $window.setTimeout(function() {
          attrs.$set('style', 'margin-top: ' + heightFactory.getMarginTop() + 'px');
          console.log(heightFactory.getMarginTop());
        }, 1000);


        scope.$on('content.loaded', function() {
          if (heightFactory.getMarginTop() > 0) {
            attrs.$set('style', 'margin-top: ' + heightFactory.getMarginTop() + 'px');
          }
        });
      }
    };
  }
]);

// this directive is used for each element, whichs size you want need for your calculation
angular.module('myApp').directive('setHeight', ['heightFactory',
  function(heightFactory) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        element.ready(function() {
          heightFactory.setHeight(attrs['setHeight'], element[0].offsetHeight);
          console.log(attrs['setHeight'] + ' set to ' + element[0].offsetHeight);
        });
      }
    }

  }
]);

// the algorithm for the margin is hardcoded, this service could also just return an object with the heights, and the algorithm would still be in your original directive. It depends on the use case imho.
angular.module('myApp').factory('heightFactory', [
  function() {
    var height = {};

    return {
      setHeight: function(element, value) {
        height[element] = value;
      },
      getMarginTop: function() {
        return (height['window'] - height['header'] - height['footer']) - (height['content'] + height['pagination']);
      }
    };

  }
]);
```

```css
#header {
  background-color: red;
}
#footer {
  background-color: blue;
}
#pagination {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <header id="header" set-height="header">Header</header>

  <section id="content" set-height="content">
    <p>Some Content</p>
    <p>Some Content</p>
    <p>Some Content</p>
    <p>Some Content</p>
  </section>

  <div id="some element" footer-margin>Some Element</div>
  <section id="pagination" set-height="pagination">
    1 2 3 4 5 6
  </section>
  <footer id="footer" set-height="footer">Footer</footer>

</body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .directive('FooterMargin', [

        function() {

            function calculateMargins() {

                // elements
                var $windowHeight = angular.element(window).height(),
                    $headerHeight = angular.element('#header').height(),
                    $footerHeight = angular.element('#footer').height(),
                    $paginationHeight = angular.element('#pagination').height(),
                    $contentHeight = angular.element('#content').height();

                // margin
                return ($windowHeight - $headerHeight - $footerHeight) - ($contentHeight + $paginationHeight);

            };

            return {

                restrict: 'A',

                link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

                    // optional (window resize)
                    angular.element(window).off("resize").on("resize", function(){

                      // will trigger event to get new margin
                      $scope.$broadcast('content.loaded');
                    });

                    // some event
                    $scope.$on('content.loaded', function() {

                        var marginTop = calculateMargins();

                        if (marginTop > 0) {
                            element.css('margin-top', marginTop);
                        }

                    });

                }
            };
        }


    ]);
```

Notice the use of "angular.element". This is a proxy method used as an abstraction to jQLite and jQuery.

I added a window re-size event as well. This is optional, but the idea is that if the window changes size - the footer will recalculate.

Finally,

Most of this CAN be achieved via CSS. I doubt you can't make it work. Querying the DOM for 5 elements is expensive. That said, use your discretion.

It's also good practice to define methods outside of the "LINK" method. This, in-theory, reduces the allocation of memory the browser makes when a directive is compiled and "digested".

Comment: can you explain more 'Most of this CAN be achieved via CSS'?