# can we access randomly generated twig elements of javascript in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, twig

I am trying to get value of randomly generated input value from twig in Symfony and would like to get input value. I cannot get set ng-model in twig file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a dom element in a Angular directive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429025/how-to-access-a-dom-element-in-a-angular-directive)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the value of an `<input>` field from AngularJS, you would need to have ID set on it like this:

```
<input id="RandomValue" type="text">
```

In AngularJS, do this to get the value:

```
$scope.RandomValue = angular.element('#RandomValue').val();
```

Think of `angular.element()` as `$()` from jQuery, because Angular actually does use jQuery internally.